# regular expression validtor

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio

i have text box for phone number .i need to validate it.my requiremants are

1. Take only numeric more than 10digits
2. Take symbols like (,),-,

can any one help for this.i tried

```
^[\d{10,14} +\s +\( +\)-]+$
```

but not working.

Comment: Where can the symbols be placed? Anywhere? Only after 3 digits?
Is 1,,,,,2345,(6)7890 or (0)123,456,789 valid? Are the symbols optional or mandatory?

Comment: something like: ^[0-9()-]{10,14}$

Comment: @ranjenanil - I'm just trying to clarify exactly what you are trying to match. I'm not sure if this is correct, but are you trying to match an Indian telephone number? E.g. The format defined here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_India

Comment: @Inu..post ur comment as answer..

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/) which will help you build such expression.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what is wrong with your regex (why it's not working as expected) but I'm guessing that the issue is it matches far more than it should. I.e it will match 1 or more of all the characters in your set (rather than just between 10 and 14).

I think you're mistake is that you have put way too much in your [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You've got the `+` symbol in there 3 times and it looks like your trying to use quantifiers from within the set as well, which is not allowed. Character sets are the equivalent of single character [alternations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). So, `[abc]` is the equivalent of `a|b|c`.

I'm assuming that you want the input to be between 10 and 14 numbers while still allowing any number (zero or more) of the following characters:

```
+()-,
```

As some others have suggested, you could just put the chars you want in a set and then specify the quantifier after it like this: `^[0-9()-,+]{10,14}$`. This will almost get you there. Only problem with it is that it will allow between 10 and 14 of any of these characters, so it would successfully match this:

```
,,,,,++()---
```

Which clearly you don't want (do you?)

So, in order to better solve this problem, you'll need to be more specific about what is allowed and where in the subject it is allowed. Because i don't know exactly what you want to match, i can't take you much further.

Hopefully the information I've provided here should be good enough to get you started, and if you have more questions... well that's what we're all here for right, so ask away.

To help you out with learning, below are a few resources you might find useful (this is a small subset of what's available, so do go ahead and search for yourself):

**Testing tools**

- [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) (ruby)
- [GSkinner Regex Testser](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)
- [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) (dotnet)

**Helpful info**

- [Regular-Expressions.Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Codeproject 30 Minute Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)